# Developer Console - No response from server

Tags: apex, soql, developer-console

I am not sure how to get rid of this 'No response from server' message when using Developer Consoles Query editor. I am quering the Asset object which has a little over 25 million records. I am trying to get the count of records that meets certain criteria

Here is the SOQL:

```
Select count() from Asset Where type__c NOT IN('Ticket','Plan','Promos')
```

This gives me the 'No reponse from server' message.

Please advise!

Comment: Have you tried inverting to `Type__c IN (...)`. If it's a picklist, you should be able to search the values you want instead of those you don't.

Comment: @AdrianLarson It is not a picklist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error happens if your query doesn't return within a few seconds. You can try the query again in a few seconds, it may be cached and give you a valid response, or you can try to optimize your query by using IN instead of NOT IN:

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM Asset WHERE Type__c IN ('Value1','Value2','Value3')
```

Or, run this code from Execute Anonymous:

```
System.debug([
 Select count() from Asset Where type__c NOT IN('Ticket','Plan','Promos')
]);
```

Apex has a much longer timeout period, so this should work.

You can get to Execute Anonymous by way of the Debug > Open Execute Anonymous Window.

You can also run this query from another tool, like Workbench, VS Code, etc, all of which have a longer timeout period.

Comment: You have always provided the best answer here in my experience. You are amazing. Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a dev console timeout setting somewhere that can be tweaked ?

Comment: @NagenSahu No, it's fixed to some value. I haven't debugged this, but it seems to be just a few seconds, much shorter than most other tools.